# Bug in the official Android Fragments training sample?

Tags: android, oop, android-fragments, android-view

It seems to me that there must be a bug in the Android Fragments demo.

As background, Fragments are apparently sometimes instantiated by the Android OS and thus [need a public no-arg constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor.
>   The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed,
>   in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this
>   constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not
>   available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state
>   restore.

But the [NewsReader demo](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html) from the official Android training on Fragments constructs the `HeadlinesFragment` class and configures it with `setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this)` from `NewsReaderActivity.onCreate()`.

If the Android OS re-instantiates this fragment, the `mHeadlineSelectedListener` field will be null because `HeadlinesFragment` doesn't save or restore its state.  It can't anyhow, because I believe it's impossible to persist a reference to an `Activity`.

Furthermore, I noticed that the [`Fragment` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) states:

> It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other
>   constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be
>   called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be
>   supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved
>   by the Fragment with getArguments().

On the other hand, it seems they perform instantiation and configuration (sort-of) correctly in the preceding [`FragmentBasics`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) example.  I say "sort of" because for some reason they directly instantiate the `HeadlinesFragment` rather than via `SupportFragmentManager`, as is done in the `NewsReader` demo.  Regardless, they don't make the apparent mistake of calling a setter in `HeadlinesFragment` from `MainActivity`, but instead let `HeadlinesFragment` take responsibility for finding the `OnArticleSelectedListener`, where it does so during `onAttach()`.

Is this a bug in the `NewsReader` example or am I missing something?  In the meantime, I've submitted an [Android documentation issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37755).

Comment: There's a lot missing from official documentation about fragment's actual life cycle. In another example they used a static `getInstance(int arg)` to create a fragment with preset args. Which failed to work when a config change happened, and System just called default constructor instead.

Comment: Wouldn't this be fixed if the example authors saved state from within the fragment?

Comment: Yes, It would, only in case developer doesn't intentionally want to recreate fragment. If you write a fragment with such factory methods, it also makes this fragment unsuitable to embed in XML layout. And its really hard to deliver init parameters to a fragment that's inflated out from XML. The highest doubt I have is in the life-cycle differences of an XML embedded fragment and one added from activity code, during a configuration change.